# Making an if statement wait in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my Android app wait a few seconds before it tries to do an if statement. I've heard some people say not to use the thread.sleep() method, so is there a better way to do it? This is what I tried to do, which doesn't work

```
try {
   Thread.sleep( 1500 );
}
catch( InterruptedException e ) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
if( playerimage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ) {
   currentscore.setText( "Game over" );
}
```

Comment: Use handler. You can wait your process by handler

Comment: you are clearly blocking the ui thread. don't. ever. more generally, if you find yourself in a situation where you consider having a thread explicitly wait, chances are there is something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work, create a handler, and wait 1.5 seconds :) This is generally the best way of doing it, its the most tidy and also probably the best on memory too as its not really doing too much, plus as it's only doing it once it is the most simple solution.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
   public void run() { 
   if (playerimage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      currentscore.setText("Game over");
      }
   } 
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 

             if (playerimage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
             currentscore.setText("Game over");
     }, 1500);
```

simple Example of Handler .. this will wait 1500 ms and will add whats inside the Runnable to the Looping Queue on the same Thread that created the Handler.